# Member variables vs setArguments in Fragments

Tags: java, android, coding-style, android-fragments

I've noticed that in the Android reference for Fragments (notably [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#AlertDialog)) that they do a couple of things different from what I'd expect:

1). Use `public static foo newInstance()` method rather than a constructor.
2). Pass values to onCreateDialog using setArguments rather than member variables.

I've read that newInstance appears to be preferrable when using reflection. However I really don't understand why they're passing parameters via a bundle. I'd have though using member variables would be safer (not using a string to fetch from a map) and would have less of an overhead.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 50):

I've also stumbled upon this and found a few advantages to using the arguments `Bundle` over instance fields:

- If it's in a `Bundle` the Android system knows about it and can create and destroy your `Fragment` (using the mandatory parameterless/default constructor and usual lifecycle methods), and just pass in the arguments bundle again. This way no arguments get lost on a low memory killing spree or the eventual orientation changes (this often hits me on first deploy to a real device after development in the less-rotating emulator).
- You can just pass the extras `Bundle` of an `Activity` as-is to a `Fragment` embedded in the layout; e.g. I often use this when I have an `Activity` that displays a `Fragment` "fullscreen" and needs some ID (or `ContentProvider` URI) to know what to display/do. I sometimes even add more stuff to a `Bundle` (or a copy) before I pass it on, e.g.

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) { // not a re-creation
      final Bundle args = new Bundle(getIntent().getExtras());
      args.putInt(CoverImageFragment.BACKGROUND_RESOURCE, android.R.color.black);
      final Fragment fragment = CoverImageFragment.newInstance(args);
      getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(android.R.id.content, fragment)
        .commit();
    }
  }
  ```
- It keeps the way of developing a `Fragment` close to that of an `Activity`, i.e. `Bundle` as "input parameters, no exceptions".

As for the downsides you mentioned:

- I think the overhead is minimal because you most likely won't be querying the `Bundle` in a tight loop, so getting your argument data out once in `onCreate()`,  `onViewCreate()`, etc. isn't that bad.
- For type-safety, `Bundle` has all the different `getXXXX()` methods, and even overloads to provide a default value if a something is missing/optional :)

As for the `newInstance()` methods, I think of them as an easy way to encapsulate the `new` and `setArguments()` calls for my `Fragment`; I sometimes provide an additional `MyFragment newInstance(String singleIdOfWhatToDisplay)` that creates both the `Bundle` and `Fragment` in one go and returns a ready-to-go `Fragment` instance.

Comment: What does a newInstance method achieve what a constructor would not achieve? I can call `setArguments` from a constructor.

Comment: @Matthias I think it's just better style to create factory methods in these situations...

Comment: newInstance is not a factory method (as in the factory method pattern if that's what you mean--see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern); it's static and hence cannot be overridden, nor is it generic with respect to the type it returns. From what I can tell it bears no advantage over using a constructor directly other than personal preference. However, I vaguely remember that Fragments need a default constructor? Perhaps the idea here is to not having to define 2 ctors, one taking the bundle arguments and one that's empty. Best guess.

Comment: I do not understand this. If we use setArguments, the Bundle that we pass is somehow preserved? HOW? When the Activity and Fragment are recreated after rotation, WHY would the Bundle that we created in our host Activity be magically available again to instantiate the Fragment? Unless the Bundle used to instantiate the Fragment was itself manually preserved in the Activity, would it not naturally be lost when the Activity is recreated? I still see NO difference between calling setArguments and writing a setter in the Fragment.

Comment: could you tell please, how can I pass a bundle as-is to Fragment embedded into xml layout?

Comment: @Matthias I think it's appropriate to call newInstance is a 'factory' method - any method that returns a 'newed' instance can correctly be deemed a 'factory' method (not sure about 'factory method' tho ;-).

Comment: @rmirabelle: **1)** The bundle you pass with setArguments actually is not preserved, but mearly a starting point for the fragment/activity (which are called without parameter). **2)** Before your activity/fragment is destroyed because of e.g. orientation change `onSaveInstanceState` will be called (which you should overwrite and save whatever you want to preserve (in yet a different bundle (the `savedInstanceState` bundle ;-)))) **3)** On creation (`onCreate`) you check if you got params from newInstance (`getArguments()!=null`) or saved parameteres (`savedInstanceState!=null`). Easy (J/K) ;-)

Comment: @Levit 1) I'm pretty sure arguments bundle is preserved. From the source: *Supply the construction arguments for this fragment. This can only be called before the fragment has been attached to its activity; that is, you should call it immediately after constructing the fragment. The arguments supplied here will be retained across fragment destroy and creation.*

Comment: @Levit 2) The arguments bundle is a way of saying "these are things needed to **create** this fragment". The saved instance state is a way of saying "this is the **current state** of my fragment". The arguments bundle can't be changed after fragment is attached to activity. So you can *kind of* think of the arguments bundle as a set of constants, and the saved instance state bundle as a set of variables. You can use variables to store constants but why would you?

Comment: @Philipp Reichart I'd be careful about just passing on the bundle from activity to fragment. If you do that the fragment will have to know about keys from multiple other classes. Then you've really tightly coupled your fragment to the activity that started it **and** to the thing that started your activity.

Comment: @tir38: You are right, the initial bundle is preserved as well (just checked). But as I said, it still serves mearly as a starting point (or as you said: "like a set of constants" (figuratively)), and the `savedInstanceState` should hold the current ("variable") state. So except for the first part of my comment (it *not* being preserved), I think it is a correct summary of the matter, don't you think? But maybe you could supply a more detailed answer concerning this matter, you would have my upvote for sure! Many people are still confused about the "bundle issue" and you supply good info here!

Answer (score 21):

I found this to be a HIGHLY confusing issue (one of many that litter the Android landscape).

`setArguments()` is a workaround for Android's very unhelpful need to have a parameter-less constructor available for Fragments.

My confusion came in waves. First, the methods you naturally override in your `Fragment` (e.g. `onCreate`, `onCreateView`) receive a `Bundle` parameter that represents the `savedInstanceState` of your `Fragment`. This instance state apparently has **NOTHING** whatsoever to do with the values you store via `setArguments()` and retrieve via `getArguments()`. Both use a `Bundle`, both `Bundles` are likely to be accessed within the same overridden method, neither have anything to do with each other.

Second, it's unclear how Android uses `setArguments()`. Android calls your parameter-less constructor to rebuild your `Fragment` on rotate, but apparently ALSO will call whichever `setArguments()` method was last called when the `Fragment` was constructed.

Huh????

Amazing, but true.  All of this creating `Bundles` with `setArguments()` madness exists to compensate for the need of a parameter-less `Fragment` constructor.

In short, I'm using the static `newInstance` method to create my `Fragment`.

```
public MyFragment() {
    //satisfy Android
}

public static MyFragment newInstance(long record_id) {
    Log.d("MyFragment", "Putting " + record_id + " into newInstance");
    MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putLong("record_id", record_id);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /**
     * Perform an immediate check of arguments,
     * which ARE NOT the same as the bundle used
     * for saved instance state.
     */
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if(args != null) {
        record_id = args.getLong("record_id");
        Log.d("MyFragment", "found record_id of " + String.valueOf(record_id));
    }
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        //now do something with savedInstanceState
    }
}
```

Comment: Why just not set private fields in `newInstance`?

Comment: @CAMOBAP because Android won't call `newInstance` to re-initialize the Fragment on device rotation (or whenever it decides it needs to destroy, then rebuild the instance  - which could be at any time and for any reason). Instead, Android will always automatically call the default no-args constructor to recreate the fragment. `setArguments` and `getArguments` implement Android's workaround for this horrifying limitation.

Answer (score 10):

I am pretty new to Android programming but this is my current understanding of the issue:

The constructor for Fragments *cannot* have any parameters. When your activity is paused your Fragment can be released. Before your activity is resumed, the system creates a new version of your Fragment calling the constructor. If a non-default constructor is used, how is Android supposed to know what the types and values are for the arguments to your Fragments constructor?

I don't believe that bundle is released. The bundle is kept around precisely so that it can be passed back to your Fragment after it has been recreated with the default constructor.

Philipp Reichart eluded to this in his post (actually more than eluded.)

Comment: Are you sure you're new to Android? That's a concise, well-crafted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add one more drawback to arguments is that you have to dynamically create fragments. As arguments does not work very well if you creating from the xml. And I really hate that.

Comment: You can access the activity args from fragment with `getActivity().getIntent().getExtras()` and it works well.

Comment: I think for passing the arguments you need to create fragments in the code. If you define the fragment in the xml, I don't remember is there a way to pass arguments. Is there?

Comment: I'm experimenting with doing a setArguments(new Bundle()) in my zero parameter constructor for my Fragment to get around the problem with not being able to use get/setArguments in an xml instantiated fragment.