# Exception when showing a dialog after orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity and a fragment inside it.inside fragment, there is a button, and on click of button a dialog shows.

Everything works, until user do a orientation change and click button after it.
IllegalStateException(cannot perform this action after onsaveinstancestate) occurs when user clicks button after orientation change. I'm using android support framework.

Anybody have any idea regarfing this?

Activity Code

```
 public void openMoreDialog(String shareData, String link) {
    DialogFragment dialog = new MoreDialog(shareData, link);
    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "MoreDialog");
}
```

Fragment Code

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mControl = (ActivityControl)activity;
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
   ImageButton moreButton = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.moreButton);
              moreButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mControl.openMoreDialog(shareData, link);
                }
              });
   return rootView;
}
```

FragmentDialog code

```
public class MoreDialog extends DialogFragment {

private String mShareData;
private String mLink;

public MoreDialog(String shareData, String link){
    mShareData = shareData;
    mLink = link;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.more_dialog, null);
    Button openBtn = (Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.openBtn);
    openBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openLink(mLink);
        }
    });     

    Button shareBtn = (Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.shareBtn);
    shareBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            shareNews(mShareData);
        }
    }); 

    builder.setView(dialogView);      
    return builder.create();
}

private void openLink(String link){

}

private void shareNews(String data){

}
```

}

Comment: how does your dialogfragment constructor looks like?

Comment: added DialogFragment code

Comment: Have you tried switching to onCreateView() instead of onCreateDialog()? You can imitate a dialog using a layout xml that looks like it.

Comment: `View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
   ImageButton moreButton = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.moreButton);`

Comment: First View is called "rootView", then you inflate View called "v"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helpful link & solution how to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17413324/619673 and btw, constructor in fragment must be empty! Documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

> public Fragment ()
>   Added in API level 11
>
> Default constructor.
>
> Every fragment must have an empty constructor, so
>   it can be instantiated when restoring its activity's state. It is
>   strongly recommended that subclasses do not have other constructors
>   with parameters, since these constructors will not be called when the
>   fragment is re-instantiated; instead, arguments can be supplied by the
>   caller with setArguments(Bundle) and later retrieved by the Fragment
>   with getArguments().
>
> Applications should generally not implement a constructor. The first
>   place application code an run where the fragment is ready to be used
>   is in onAttach(Activity), the point where the fragment is actually
>   associated with its activity. Some applications may also want to
>   implement onInflate(Activity, AttributeSet, Bundle) to retrieve
>   attributes from a layout resource, though should take care here
>   because this happens for the fragment is attached to its activity.